# Итератор для пользовательского типа и цикл for each

Tags: vba

Добрый день. Есть ли возможность подружить написанный мной класс (внутри содержится некоторая коллекция\массив) с For Each циклом, как это делается в классе Collection? Пример:

```
Dim example As New Collection
example.Add 2
example.Add 3
Dim elem As Variant
For Each elem In example
    Debug.Print elem
Next elem
```

Видно, что у example никакая функция, возвращающая список значений, явно не вызывается при передачи в For Each цикл. Как можно реализовать такое поведение для любого другого типа? Как я понимаю, в самом языке используется какой-то служебный механизм, реализующий концепцию итератора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Ваш класс содержит коллекцию, то это можно сделать.
Добавляете метод (пусть коллекция в классе называется `mycollection`)

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = mycollection.[_NewEnum]    
End Property
```

Затем экспортируете Ваш класс в файл, открываете его в текстовом редакторе и добавляете в этот метод строку `Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4`. В итоге он должен выглядеть так:

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = mycollection.[_NewEnum]    
End Property
```

Импортируете этот класс вместо Вашего и всё будет работать.

Подробнее можно прочитать тут https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5321/attributes#t=201608230625133754538

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что такого поведения для массива уже добиться не реально (ну или, как пример, для пользовательской реализации бинарного дерева)?

Comment: Сам, к сожалению, использовал только коллекции, поэтому про массивы ничего не скажу. Может кто еще чего подскажет.